# Why am I getting an exception "cannot access disposed object" sometimes?

Tags: c#

I have this code in my background `DoWork` event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    while (true)
    {

        if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (tempCpuValue >= (float?)nud1.Value || tempGpuValue >= (float?)nud1.Value)
            {
                soundPlay = true;
                blinking_label();
                NudgeMe();
            }
            else
            {
                soundPlay = false;
                stop_alarm = true;

            }
            cpuView();
            gpuView();
        }
    }
}
```

In the `cpuView()` method I have this code:

```
if (InvokeRequired)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => data = new List<string>()));
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => data.Add("Gpu Temeprature --- " + sensor.Value.ToString())));
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.DataSource = null));
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.DataSource = data));
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.Invalidate()));
}
```

The exception/error was this time on the line:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => data = new List<string>()));
```

And this is my Form1 closing event:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you Sure you want to Exit. Click Yes to Confirm and No to continue", "WinForm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

The error/exception happened once i quit my application clicked on the red x on the top right corner and selected YES to quit.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So part of the issue here is that you're not leveraging the functionality that a BGW gives you.  If you're calling `Invoke` from inside of `DoWork` it means you're not really using a BGW to do it's job.  In your case, you should just be calling `ReportProgress` on the BGW, and then have a `ProgressChanged` event handler that updates the UI based on the progress.  You can pass in a parameter that represents the data to update the UI with, so you can construct your list inside of `DoWork`, pass it via `ReportProgress`, and then set the `DataSource` in the `ProgressChanged` event handler.

Now the BGW is responsible for not reporting progress once the worker has been canceled.

Comment: Servy thanks. If you could show me an example of how to do it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user2065612 I've described exactly what you need to do in step by step instructions.  There is also a large number of detailed examples of using this behavior on the web and the MSDN documentation for the background worker.  You do not need me to give you the exact, entirely finished code.  You should take this opportunity to learn how to learn how to use this functionality yourself, because it's something you're going to need to do a *lot* if doing even a bit of UI programming; you simply need to be able to do this on your own.

Answer (score 0):

As a Form is closed, its child controls and the form itself are disposed. However, WinForms continues to process pending Invokes on the UI thread. That's why it raises a "cannot access disposed objects".

`Application.DoEvents()` is often described as the evil, but its job is to process all pending messages on the UI thread.

Having the background threads finished in the Close event is not enough.

That's why I suggest you to add an `Application.DoEvents()` before any Dispose, so the pending Invokes are being flushed, then the form will Close gracefully.

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you Sure you want to Exit. Click Yes to Confirm and No to continue", "WinForm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
else
{
    if (backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    }

    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

In case of the Application.DoEvents() is too hacky for you, you can swallow the ObjectDisposedException by using a extension method that encapsulates the InvokeRequired pattern:

```
public static void InvokeIfRequired(this Control control, Action action)
{
    try
    {
        if (control.IsDisposed)
            return;

        if (control.InvokeRequired)
            control.Invoke(action);
        else
            action();
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException)
    {
        // There is nothing much we can do when an Invoke is pending on a disposed control 
        // the other exceptions will bubble up normally
    }
}
```